# Does AWS Javascript SDK v3 automatically read credentials from local config?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, credentials

I'm looking at this page [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript...](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html) and it seems to imply that the SDK will look at `~/.aws/credentials` and take the `[default]` profile if there is no AWS_PROFILE environment var.

I'm running a NextJS app on my local machine trying to list S3 buckets, getting `Error: Credential is missing`.

I would really love not to have to specify the creds in env vars as I'll be deploying the app to ECS later where it will use an IAM Role for access.

Here's my code:

```
import { ListBucketsCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { s3Client } from '../lib/s3Client';

const S3Buckets = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getS3Buckets() {
            const input = {};
            const command = new ListBucketsCommand(input);
            const res = await s3Client.send(command);
            console.log(res);
        }
        getS3Buckets();
    }, []);

    return <div>{/* S3 Buckets eventually listed here */}</div>;
};

export default S3Buckets;
```

with the s3Client helper as below:

```
import { S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

export const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION });
```